# execute a subcommand in a different directory as the current one in fish?

Tags: shell, fish, subcommand

I want to move a file from a directory different from the current directory. This is the solution I thought of:

`mv (cd ~/Downloads; ls -t | head -1 | xargs -I {} readlink -f {}) ./`

There is probably a better way, but along the way I found that my expectation of the change of directory staying inside the subcommand was wrong: Running cd changes the directory where `mv` is being executed.

So, is there a way to change directories only for the current subcommand, without affecting the top command?

Comment: Sort of borderline, since it's *kind of* about "shell scripting", but I'd really recommend this type of "general `fish` use" question for [Unix and Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow (which is for "programming questions").  Just be aware in case you get downvotes, that others may not feel it is quite as "borderline".

Comment: Looks firmly on topic to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, many of us coming from Posix shells like `bash` or `zsh` are used to being able to run a command substitution like this using `$()` or just backticks and leave the parent shell environment untouched.  It's a nice trick, IMHO.

On the other hand, `fish` doesn't automatically create a subshell when using its command substitution operator `()`.  There's a [feature request here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1439) for that, but the workaround (as suggested there) is fairly straightforward -- Just explicitly create a subshell inside the command substitution.  E.g.:

```
mv (fish -c 'cd ~/Downloads; ls -t | head -1 | xargs -I {} readlink -f {}') ./
```

The downside is that syntax highlighting/checking doesn't work in the quoted text, and quoting/escaping rules get more complicated.